# flexbox column layout responsive with column reorder without fixed height

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox, css-multicolumn-layout

I'm trying to accomplish this with flexbox =>

desktop :

```
|         |   | block 1 |
| block 2 |
|         |   | block 3 |
```

mobile :

```
block 1
block 2
block 3
```

I came to this

```
.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flew-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

.myblocks.block2 {
  order: -1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .cont {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

But this **doesn't work** until I set a fixed `height` to `.cont` and a `flex-basis` to `.block1`

---

Questions :

- *is there a way with flexbox to accomplish this, without fixed height ?*
- *is flexbox the right tool for this ?*

---

NB: I'm using Bulma

Comment: Do you know the width of block 2?

Comment: I do, in % though